# Automating method execution in java

Tags: java

I have 6 functions which I need to run in specific time intervals:

```
public void runFirst() {
    System.out.println("First method");
}

public void runSecond() {
    System.out.println("Second method");
}

public void runThird() {
    System.out.println("Third method");
}

public void runFourth() {
    System.out.println("Fourth method");
}

public void runFifth() {
    System.out.println("Fifth method");
}

public void runSixth() {
    System.out.println("Sixth method");
}
```

I need to run "first" as soon as i click the button, second must be after 65 seconds, third 20 seconds after second, fourth 15 seconds after the third one and so on, at the time i'm using `Thread.sleep` but i will need to make it without sleeps.

What is the best way and can someone show me some example based on my methods.

Comment: You want to do this *without* `Thread.sleep`?

Comment: Yes if it's possible. If no, how can I make it to not pause my entire application for the sleep period?

Comment: Put it on a separate `Thread`.

Comment: Look in to [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Create a Thread class and another Class for your methods

Now:

```
public class ThreadTest implements Runnable {

    private int functionNumber;
    private int time2start;
    private YourClass obj;

    public ThreadTest(int functionNumber, int time2start, YourClass obj) {
        this.functionNumber = functionNumber;
        this.time2start = time2start;
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(time2start);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }//Time Delay before executing methods
        switch (functionNumber) {
            case 1:
                obj.runFirst();
                break;
            case 2:
                obj.runSecond();
                break;
            case 3:
                obj.runThird();
                break;
            case 4:
                obj.runFourth();
                break;
            //keep adding
        }
    }
}
```

then Class for your methods :

```
public class YourClass {

    public void runFirst() {
        System.out.println("First method");
    }

    public void runSecond() {
        System.out.println("Second method");
    }

    public void runThird() {
        System.out.println("Third method");
    }

    public void runFourth() {
        System.out.println("Fourth method");
    }

    public void runFifth() {
        System.out.println("Fifth method");
    }

    public void runSixth() {
        System.out.println("Sixth method");
    }
}
```

Now this is the method for onClick event for the button:

```
//on button click

ThreadTest th1 = new ThreadTest(1, 0, obj);//here obj is YourClass
ThreadTest th2 = new ThreadTest(2, 65000, obj);//65 SECONDS
//... keep adding

Thread thread1 = new Thread(th1);
Thread thread2 = new Thread(th2);
//...keep adding

thread1.start();
thread2.start();
//...keep adding
```

Comment: Dude you are a gem... thank you very much. I would upvote but i can't :/

Comment: looks like reinventing the wheel ... why not use existing utily like Timer or SheduledExecutorService ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Quartz. While clicking the button you can get system current time and add a new scheduled job to run on specific date&time. So Quartz will handle it to run on the time.

Another way is to create a new Thread and define on it the sleep period of time and let that to run function.

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you use

```
Thread.sleep
```

and run this code in different thread (then, the whole app wont stop on sleep)

Comment: ovonel "will need to make it without sleeps".

Comment: ovonel "Yes if it's possible. If no, how can I make it to not pause my entire application for the sleep period?"

Comment: It's ok, I will continue with sleeps but i'll put it on different thread. Thanks everyone for help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to check the [#wait(timeout)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long)) method, the one with timeout.

Quote:

> "... the thread lies dormant until the specified amount of real time
>   has elapsed..."

Answer (score 0):

To run a task after some time, you should use a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html), which is a *"A facility for threads to schedule tasks for future execution in a background thread. "*.

It frees you from creating your own thread : less error-prone and easier. It can manage several scheduled tasks. Beware though, these task should be short-lived (other they will block the thread used for scheduling puropose by the timer)..

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ExecutorService`. The basic idea would be something like this:

```
    // "Global" resource
    final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5); // Adjust threadpool size

    ...
    // inside onclick() processing        
    ScheduledFuture<Void> future1 = executorService.schedule(new Callable<Void>() {
        @Override Void call() {
            try {
                runFirst();
            } finally {
                scheduleFuture2();
            }
        }
    },
    65,
    TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    ...

    void scheduleFuture2() {            
        ScheduledFuture<Void> future2 = executorService.schedule(new Callable<Void>() {
            @Override Void call() {
                try {
                    runSecond();
                } finally {
                    scheduleFuture3();
                }                    
            }
        },
        20,
        TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    ...

    void scheduleFuture3() {            
        ScheduledFuture<Void> future3 = executorService.schedule(new Callable<Void>() {
            @Override Void call() {
                try {
                    runThird();
                } finally {
                    scheduleFuture4();
                }                    
            }
        },
        15,
        TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    ...
    // And so on
```

Some notes:

- if `runFirst()` , `runSecond()`, ... perform Swing / AWT UI operations, the you should proably make use of [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) inside those methods
- don't forget to invoke `executorService.shutdown()` when you not going to use this mechanism anymore. If you forget about it, you will "leak" threads.
- The references to `Void` above (uppercase "V") are intentional: we are using the `Void` class and not the `void` type

Answer (score 0):

Use a [**ScheduledExecutorService**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)!

```
{
    ScheduledExecutorService worker = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    worker.execute(() -> runFirst());
    worker.schedule(() -> runSecond(), 65, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    worker.schedule(() -> runThird(), 85, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    worker.schedule(() -> runFourth(), 100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    worker.schedule(() -> runFifth(), 110, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    worker.schedule(() -> runSixth(), 115, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    worker.shutdown();
}
```

If you cannot use Java 8 for some reason, use [anonymous implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) of [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) instead of [Lambda expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html):

```
// worker.schedule(() -> runSixth(), 115, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
worker.schedule(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runSixth();
    }}, 115, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: I have been waited  0 + 65 + 85 + 100 + 110 + 115 = 475 seconds :) , and your program work very nice!

Comment: Yes, schedule with wait 0 is the same as "execute". The program will not wait for 475 sec, the consecutive calls to "schedule" will not schedule it after the last one, the time is from the time of the scheduling. So it will wait for a total of 115 sec (The time between 5:th and 6:th is just 5 sec in this example)

Comment: thank you for your notice. I have a little confused. 115 seconds.

Comment: The question states "third 20 seconds after second" which is not exactly what happens here, especially if the method perform some long operation. To be perfect, each task should schedule the next one.

Comment: True, if that is important then the first task will have to schedule the next one. It doesn't say 20 sec after the last one "completed" though, so that is ambiguous (Also, it will clutter the tasks)